# How to eliminate the leading coefficient in this congruence?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

$$ax^2 = b \bmod m$$

I am trying to get rid of the $a$ so I can apply Tonelli-Shanks to the result to solve for $x$. But since $a$ and $m$ are not always coprime, I cannot always multiply both sides by the inverse of $a$ mod $m$.

In summary, I am trying to change it to form $x^2 = c \bmod d$.

Assume that $\gcd(a,b,m) = 1$.

Comment: You said $a$ and $m$ are not always copirme. Then in the end you say $\gcd(a,b,m)=1$. So what do you want?

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain You can have $\gcd(a,b,m)=1$ without having $\gcd(a,m)=1$. It just means that you can no longer divide the entire equation by some constant factor. For example $\gcd(5,10,7) = 1$ but $\gcd(5,10) = 5$.

Comment: First compute $\gcd(a,m)$. If this does not divide $b$, we have a very efficient algorithm, just say no. In particular, if $\gcd(a,m)\gt 1$ and $\gcd(a,b,m)=1$ as in your post, say no. Else divide everything by the gcd and apply Tonelli-Shanks.

Comment: @AndréNicolas That is what I thought but I was not confident about it. Let $g=\gcd(a,m)$. If $g$ does not divide $b$, no solution. Otherwise, we have $x^2 = (b/g)(a/g)^{-1} \bmod m/g$. Is this right?

Comment: Yes. The inverse of $a/g$ is taken mod $m/g$. There may ultimately be reason to give the answers mod $m$, not mod $m/g$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I assume, then, that any result from this congruence would just be multiplied by $g$ at the end?

Comment: No, we get results mod $m/g$ which we convert to $m$ by adding any multiple of $m/g$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a$ and $m$ are not coprime, but $\gcd(a,b,m) = 1$, then $a$ and $m$ have a factor that does not divide $b$. This means that the congruence $ax^2 \equiv b \pmod m$ has no solutions. Indeed, this is the same as asking for a solution in $x,y$ to $ax^2 + my = b$, but the left side is divisible by the common factor of $a$ and $m$, while the right side is not.

In all other cases, you can divide through the $\gcd(a,b,m)$ and proceed as normal.